# Ant-Design CSS not loading properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am having an issue with rendering my Ant-Design CSS on the first-render using React.js. I have a very basic page, that is just rendering a button.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Button } from 'antd';

const LoginPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default LoginPage;
```

I am trying to import the Ant-Design modules through the config-overrides.js file, as per the documentation:

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    fixBabelImports('import', {
        libraryName: 'antd',
        libraryDirectory: 'es',
        style: 'css',
    }),
);
```

Here is my index.js file:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import 'normalize.css';

import App from './components/App/App';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { fetchUser } from './actions';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

store.dispatch(fetchUser()).then(() => console.log(store.getState()));


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And here is my App.js and App.css for more reference:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginPage from '../LoginPage/LoginPage';
import DashboardPage from '../DashboardPage/DashboardPage';

import { Spin } from 'antd';

import './App.css';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({loggedIn: true });
    }

    render() {
       return <LoginPage/>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        user: state.currUser
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

```css
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

However, on the first render it will only show a normal button, before fixing itself a second later. Here are two images that show the problem:
[image: Image One - First Render]

And here is the page after the second render:
[image: Image Two - Second Render]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just import this file in your jsx file or js file:

> If you import it in App.jsx file once then no need to import in other files

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

Comment: After adding antd css, style is working but page scroll blocked, any idea?

Comment: page scrolling blocked after adding antd.css. Then Imported module specific css file only   as @rawat answer and solved the issue

Answer (score 7):

Add `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`

To the top of either/both of App.css and Index.css.

Hope that helps! .

P.S - If you are using a single component for instance lets say Input, then import only that part.

import 'antd/es/input/style/index.css';

Comment: page scrolling blocked after adding antd.css. Then Imported module specific css file only and solved the issue

Answer (score 7):

Do NOT import the root styles from ant, as they contain some global styles, unfortunately, and will affect yours styling anyway, this was [addressed](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/9363) a lot of times to them, but still I found the only solution is to directly import the components styling like this (replace `select` with your component):
`import "antd/lib/select/style/index.css";`

Answer (score 6):

this below import is used my react project with create-react-app cli
import 'antd/dist/antd.css',
use this import to your root component.

Comment: By root component, would that be App or Provider (I am using Redux)?

Answer (score 4):

In your index.js file, you can import ant style files:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Answer (score 2):

As of this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33327), please use the minified version.

```
import "antd/dist/antd.min.css";
```